# Making two classes work together in Java

Tags: java, symbol-not-found

I am trying to compile my NameRecord.java file, but I keep getting the following error: cannot find symbol num = input.nextLine(); It's saying the Scanner input is the issue, but I initialized and populate the Scanner input before I call the NameRecord class.

Both of these classes are in the same directory, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is the class that calls the NameRecord class. It does not compile I keep getting a symbol not found Method NameRecord(String):

I left out a couple of methods that are also included in this class to conserve space.

Comment: Where do you define "input" for num = input.nextLine(); ?

Comment: You've got much more than compilation problems as your NameRecord class is broken in several ways. The NameRecord class shouldn't have any user interface code in it at all, and there should be no static variables in this class, else all objects of this class will be worthless as all will hold the very same information. You should start over and make this a true OOPs class with instance variables, getters, setters, etc... All user interface code should be in the GUI, not the NameRecord class.

Comment: you either have to pass the `Scanner` to the `NameRecord` Class (a bad idea) or you should read the `Scanner` before calling `NameRecord` and pass the String you read in.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that is preventing this from compiling is that the `NameRecord` class has no way of knowing about `input`.  This is an issue of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). The only place where your code "knows about" `input` is within the `try-catch` block in the `main` method of `NameGameFrame`.  You should pass the `String` returned by `input.nextLine()` to `NameRecord` for this to work the way you want it to.

That being said, this is one of about 20 problems with your code.

Comment: While your advice is technically correct, we should not encourage bad program design. So please change your answer and don't encourage him to use Scanner in the NameRecord class. That means he shouldn't pass in any Scanner parameter in.

Comment: I built these classes separately to test functionality then tried to make them work together. How do I make one class see the the other class?